# How to add Masonry options to isotope using images loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with firefox and chrome not rendering the proper amount of columns when using Jquery Isotope and the images loaded option. Safari shows 3 columns all the time. However firefox and chrome sometimes only show 2. All of my images have the same width 28.333%. I have tried changing that to a lower number but it does not effect anything.

Here is what I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 var $container = $('#artContent'),
 filters = {};

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
$container.isotope({
itemSelector : '.isotopeItem'
});
});
```

I tried this which resulted in breaking all the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 var $container = $('#artContent'),
 filters = {};

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
$container.isotope({
itemSelector : '.isotopeItem',
masonry: { columnWidth: 33.333% }

});
});
```

Has anyone else had this issue? Or know of how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If your using % in columnWidth, it needs to be like so (note the single quotes):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 var $container = $('#artContent'),
 filters = {};

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
$container.isotope({
itemSelector : '.isotopeItem',
masonry: { columnWidth: '33.333%' }

});
});
```